# Error : 'A Value used in the formula is of the wrong data type' with User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a User Defined Function.

I get an error

> A Value used in the formula is of the wrong data type

I am trying to build a function that adding one comment, will also add the comment to another location as the comments always come in pairs.

```
Public Function AddComments(vesselCell As Variant, shopCell As Variant, comment As String) As Variant

    Range(vesselCell).AddComment (comment)

    Worksheets("Shop").Range(shopCell).Value = comment

End Function
```

I have singled it out to the third line of code causing the problem.

The setup currently is the Vessel Cell will be a comment added to the sheet, and then the Shop sheet has a section for comments as a column.

Comment: a UDF cannot modify a worksheet. You can't `AddComment` or set `Range.Value` in a UDF. A UDF takes inputs, computes a result, and *returns that result* to the calling cell. Nothing more, nothing less; if you need VBA code to modify a sheet, you want a *macro*, not a UDF. Make that a `Public Sub` procedure. Also if `vesselCell` and `shopCell` are meant to be `Range` objects, why not declare them as such?

Comment: I’m new to VBA (no excuse) and actually just found that I’m not able to modify the sheet through a UDF. I had it as a string, and as a variant because it was saying the values didn’t match. My thought on the ‘Range’ was wondering how I would give it the cell address. In my mind, the ‘Range’ type is just Range without the cell address.  I come from a Javascript background, is there a way to output like a console.log in VBA? I’ve been inputting the result I want to see in a random empty cell to see the result.

Comment: `Debug.Print` would be your `console.log`; use Ctrl+G to bring up the immediate pane / console :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `vesselCell` and `shopCell` are both `Range` objects, `Range(vesselCell)` and `Worksheets("Shop").Range(shopCell)` are part of the problem.

Make them `Range`, not `Variant`.

```
vesselCell.AddComment comment
shopCell.Value = comment
```

Now, this code isn't legal in a UDF. Make your procedure a `Sub` procedure (remove the `As Variant` return type), and invoke it from other VBA code, or attach it to a shape or button's `OnAction` property.

User-Defined Functions take inputs, compute a result, *and then return that result* to the calling cell: your code not returning anything is a strong indicator that a `Function` isn't appropriate here.

Comment: I just found that not long ago that i'm not able to change the sheet through a UDF. 

What do you mean by invoke it from other VBA code? I created a 'helper' function that would handle the 3rd line. I did try to change it to a Sub, but then it wasn't a function, thus not being a UDF. I appreciate your feedback/help!

Comment: It can't be a UDF, and because it's changing cells it can't be invoked by a UDF either. You need to wire up the macro to *something*. Could be an ActiveX button, for example.

Comment: @BigBen I knew I had a number of answers saying "functions take inputs", so I searched and found this instead of posting yet another dupe answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to use UDF in an excel cell.  It worked (it seemed) well when executing in VBA alone.
The technique I used to solve my problem was to put a break at the top of the VBA code, and then call the code from the excel cell (just by editing the cell and hitting enter).
When the break was taken I then stepped through.  The code stopped executing at a particular line.  I took note of where that was and then re-executed, and introduced debug into the code to check what it was doing. I found my error (s) that way, and fixed them, then stepping through to the end of the function successfully.
Removed the breakpoint and retested and it worked.
I hope this technique can help someone.